# TicTacToe Help Repaint function

Tags: java, swing, repaint, tic-tac-toe

I am creating a TicTacToe game using Java and I would like some help.

After a player wins I would like the game to ask for a rematch. This happens, but the panel of buttons isn't refreshing. I have used the "repaint" function, but it doesn't seem to work. 
Thank you in advance

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;




@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class TicTacToeGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton btn1; 
    JButton btn2;
    JButton btn3;
    JButton btn4;
    JButton btn5;
    JButton btn6;
    JButton btn7;
    JButton btn8;
    JButton btn9;
    public JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
    public int playerTurn = 0;
    public boolean win = false;
    String letter = "";
    private final String[] yesno = {" ", "Yes", "No"};

    public TicTacToeGUI(){
        window.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");   
        window.setSize(300,300);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        window.setLocation(dim.width/2-window.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-window.getSize().height/2);
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        this.addStuff();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }

    public void addStuff(){

        btn1 = new JButton("");
        btn1.addActionListener(this);

        btn2 = new JButton("");
        btn2.addActionListener(this);

        btn3 = new JButton("");
        btn3.addActionListener(this);

        btn4 = new JButton("");
        btn4.addActionListener(this);

        btn5 = new JButton("");
        btn5.addActionListener(this);

        btn6 = new JButton("");
        btn6.addActionListener(this);

        btn7 = new JButton("");
        btn7.addActionListener(this);

        btn8 = new JButton("");
        btn8.addActionListener(this);

        btn9 = new JButton("");
        btn9.addActionListener(this);

        window.add(btn1);
        window.add(btn2);
        window.add(btn3);
        window.add(btn4);
        window.add(btn5);
        window.add(btn6);
        window.add(btn7);
        window.add(btn8);
        window.add(btn9);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        playerTurn ++;

        if(playerTurn == 1 || playerTurn == 3 || playerTurn == 5 || playerTurn == 7 || playerTurn == 9) {
            letter = "X";
        }else if(playerTurn == 2 || playerTurn == 4 || playerTurn == 6 || playerTurn == 8 || playerTurn == 10){
            letter = "O";
        }

        if(e.getSource() == btn1){
            btn1.setText(letter);
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn2){
            btn2.setText(letter);
            btn2.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn3){
            btn3.setText(letter);
            btn3.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn4){
            btn4.setText(letter);
            btn4.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn5){
            btn5.setText(letter);
            btn5.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn6){
            btn6.setText(letter);
            btn6.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn7){
            btn7.setText(letter);
            btn7.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn8){
            btn8.setText(letter);
            btn8.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(e.getSource() == btn9){
            btn9.setText(letter);
            btn9.setEnabled(false);
        }
        //when horizontal lines win
        if (btn1.getText() == btn2.getText() && btn1.getText() == btn3.getText() && btn1.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }else if (btn4.getText() == btn5.getText() && btn4.getText() == btn6.getText() && btn4.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }else if (btn7.getText() == btn8.getText() && btn7.getText() == btn9.getText() && btn7.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }
        //when vertical wins
        if (btn1.getText() == btn4.getText() && btn1.getText() == btn7.getText() && btn1.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }else if (btn2.getText() == btn5.getText() && btn2.getText() == btn8.getText() && btn2.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }else if (btn3.getText() == btn6.getText() && btn4.getText() == btn9.getText() && btn3.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }
        //when diagonal wins
        if (btn1.getText() == btn5.getText() && btn1.getText() == btn9.getText() && btn1.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }else if (btn3.getText() == btn5.getText() && btn3.getText() ==btn7.getText() && btn3.getText() != ""){
            win = true;
        }

        if(win == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " WON! ");
            int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to play again?", "tictac",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (n == 0) {
                dispose();
                repaint();

            }
        } 

        else if (playerTurn == 9 && win == false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GAME IS TIED!");
            int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to play again?", "tictac",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (n == 0) {
                dispose();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need set text into Empty

```
setText("");
```

//pseudo code

```
foreach(Button temp in windows.allChild) {
    temp.setText("");
}
windows.repaint();
```